# Batch Loading data for Deep Learning

Tags: javascript

### Context

Just for learning purposes and using asynchronous iterators, I am creating a data loader that could be useful for machine learning especially images. Tensorflow has a similar function I think, much more complex.

This is a little code for loading images (or other data) and the corresponding labels files.

```javascript
import { readdir, readFile } from "node:fs/promises";
import { join, dirname } from "node:path";

// get the arrays with filenames
async function getNames(xDir, yDir){
   const xNames = await readdir(xDir);
   const yNames = await readdir(yDir); 
   return {xNames, yNames}
}


/** 
 * yPath: path to labels folder
 * xPath: path to images/data folder
 * and loads them by batches, 
 * Ready for preprocessing them, or train.
 * Out is `batch = { xs:[...], ys:[...] }`
*/
async function* getNextBatch(xDir="./images", yDir="./labels", batchSize=20){ 
   const { xNames, yNames } = await getNames(xDir, yDir)
   const xLength = xNames.length
   if( xLength !== yNames.length ){
     throw new Error(`
     Ys length: ${yNames.length} 
     Xs length: ${xLength} 
     They must be equal.
`)
}

  const lastIndex = xLength - 1

  let index = 0;
  let newBatch = { xs:[], ys:[] }
  while(index <= lastIndex){ 
   newBatch = { xs:[], ys:[] }
   const nextIndex = index + batchSize
   const available = lastIndex - nextIndex

   const iterations = available >= 0 ? nextIndex : lastIndex
   for (; index <= iterations; index++){
    const pathX = join(xDir, xNames[index])
    const pathY = join(yDir, yNames[index])
    newBatch.xs.push(await readFile(pathX))
    newBatch.ys.push(await readFile(pathY, "utf8"))
   } 
   yield newBatch
  }
}

const xPath = "./images"
const yPath = "./labels"

for await (const batch of getNextBatch(xPath, yPath, 10)){
   console.log(batch.xs)
}
```

### Comments

I could still make it so that labels can be a single file, that you can probably parse.

The idea is that users wont add a "preprocess" function as an argument, which may seem useful, but rather they can preprocess data in the outputted batch, if necessary.

I would appreciate any criticism, probably one improvement would be to lazy load the x,y file names as well.